# Getting segmentation fault in C on Ubuntu when trying to run function from .so library

Tags: c, ubuntu, shared-libraries, wireshark, fault

I am using libwireshark.so, libwsutil.so and libwiretap.so in order to make program which decodes packets like Wireshark in C on Ubuntu Linux.

I am try to run function named `epan_init()` from libwireshark.so but I get the following run-time error:

```
Enter file name: 1.pcap 

Enter print type(0-XML, 1-TEXT): 1

Init function start

Segmentaion fault (core dumped)

Process returned 139 (0x8B) execution time : 2.882 s

Press ENTER to continue.
```

SOURCE CODE:

```
#define HAVE_STDARG_H 1
#define WS_MSVC_NORETURN
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/epan.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/print.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/timestamp.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/prefs.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/column.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/epan-int.h>
#include <wireshark/wsutil/privileges.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/epan_dissect.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/proto.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/ftypes/ftypes.h>
#include <wireshark/epan/asm_utils.h>

///Prototypes
void getString(char *msg, char **input);
int init(char *filename);

///Print type of packets
typedef enum {PRINT_XML, PRINT_TEXT} print_type_t;

capture_file cfile;

int main()
{
    ///Variables
    int err;
    char *filename = NULL;
    print_type_t print_type = PRINT_XML;

    getString("Enter file name: ", &filename);

    printf("Enter print type(0-XML, 1-TEXT): ");
    scanf("%d",&print_type);

    err = init(filename);
    if(err)
    {
    printf("Main function(): Error init");
    return 1;
    }


    printf("\n\n\n%s\n\n\n",cfile.filename);


    //printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}

///Get input from user
void getString(char *msg, char **input)
{
    char buffer[100];

    printf("%s", msg);
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    *input = calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(buffer) + 1);
    strncpy(*input, buffer, strlen(buffer));
}

///
int init(char *filename)
{
    printf("Init function start\n");
    int err = 0;
    gchar *err_info = NULL;
    e_prefs *prefs_p;

    /// Called when the program starts, to enable security features and save whatever credential information we’ll need later.
    init_process_policies();
    printf("Init proccesss politices done");

    /// Init the whole epan module. Must be called only once in a program. Returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure.
    epan_init(register_all_protocols, register_all_protocol_handoffs, NULL, NULL);
    //printf("epan init done");
    cap_file_init(&cfile);
    cfile.filename = filename;

    return 0;
}

void cap_file_init(capture_file *cf)
{
    /* Initialize the capture file struct */
    memset(cf, 0, sizeof(capture_file));
    cf->snap = WTAP_MAX_PACKET_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: the `stream` outputs are buffered.  including `stdout`.  so nothing is actually displayed on the terminal until one of several kinds of events occurs.  so this kind of line: `printf("Init proccesss politices done");` does not (immediately) display on the terminal.  One simple way to correct this is to append a new line sequence to the output.  I.E. `printf("Init proccesss politices done\n");`   Note the trailing `\n`.

Comment: regarding: `cfile.filename = filename;`  This will only copy a pointer.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest: `strcpy( cfile.filename, filename );`

Comment: @user3629249 ... or use `fprintf(stderr, ...);` instead. AFAIK, when `stdout` is redirected to some file it may become even block-buffered, so newline will not suffice.

Comment: in function: `init()`, these local variables are declared: `gchar *err_info = NULL;
    e_prefs *prefs_p;` but not used within the function!   Why are they there?

Comment: @AnatolyTrosinenko,  Did I miss something?  as far as I can tell, `stdout` is not being redirected to a file.  And if there were some problem, then using `fflush( stdout )` would fix it.   I did not enumerate all the ways to force the buffered I/O to be displayed

Comment: when calling system functions, for instance `fgets()`, `calloc()`, etc the code needs to check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @user3629249 Excuse me, I just mentioned it so novices that stumble upon this question will know that redirecting an output just for their convenience may in fact make things even worse, so stderr is safer.

Comment: the call to `fgets()` will also input the trailing newline (which the user entered at the end of the filename)  The code needs to find any such newline and eliminate it.  Suggest: `char *newline = NULL;  if( (newline = strchr( buffer, '\n' )) ) {  *newline = '\0'; }`